# Detecting a range of items in an inventory

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a datapack, and I've been meaning to find out for a long time on how to test for a **range** of numbers of counts of items in a players inventory, not an exact amount.

What I'm trying to do is detect, in this case, if a player has 5 or more golden nuggets in their inventory, i've tried using many things, like using the `..` after the number, and even trying to use `min` and `max` among other things...

Comment: What types of solutions are you looking for? Are MC commands your main tool of scripting?

Comment: Mostly commands, Yes

Comment: I L O V E Y O U